# Select subset of lists from list of lists by names() position in R

Tags: r

Hello I am trying to select a subset of lists from a list of lists (df_list) by using the names() position. Below is an example of how to lists look when I use names(df_list). What is the proper way to subset say the first 5 lists?

```
df_list

[1] "2006-Fall"   "2006-Summer" "2007-Fall"   "2007-Summer" "2008-Fall"  
[6] "2008-Summer" "2009-Fall"   "2009-Summer" "2010-Summer" "2011-Spring"
[11] "2011-Summer" "2012-Fall"   "2012-Spring" "2012-Summer" "2013-Summer"
[16] "2014-Summer"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can index lists in R using the square brackets:

```
to_select <- names(df_list)[1:5] # get the first 5 names
df_list[to_select] # returns a list of 5 lists
```

Comment: Thanks for your response! Although, I get this error ... Error in df_list[[to_select]] : no such index at level 2

Comment: I just noticed I made a mistake, you should use the single bracket. I edited my answer. You can have a look here (http://www.r-tutor.com/r-introduction/list) to get more information about list slicing.